# ''MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token' when calling deployed .net core API on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am receiving the following exception in the logs and event viewer when calling an endpoint in a .Net core application (3.1):

> *'MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token*

I have this application deployed using IIS under the default web site. I had read this exception may be due to a discrepancy with Kestrel and IIS, so I updated the `CreateWebHostBuilder()` to include `UseKestrel()` and `UseIISIntegration()`, specifically in that order.

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureLogging(logger =>
  {
    logger.ClearProviders();
    logger.AddConsole();
    logger.AddDebug();
    logger.AddEventLog();
  })
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .UseKestrel()
  .UseIISIntegration();
}
```

In the appsettings file, I set the url to "Urls": "http://localhost:5001". This doesn't seem to be respected because navigating to that URL brings up 'This page cannot be displayed.' There is a port provided in the log, but *I think* this is supposed to be the kestrel port:

> *Now listening on: http://localhost:20274 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.*

I am calling the endpoint at that port. As an additional note, I have this running with the OutofProcess hosting model.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting or resolution for this issue?

Comment: There is a similar question on forums, this question seems to be related to the way of hosting: https://forums.asp.net/t/2101014.aspx?Cannot+debug+in+Visual+Studio+after+changing+the+port+number+

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. The only suggestion was to remove the UseIISIntegration(), but that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Can the .net core API template project be called normally if it is deployed in IIS?